# PHP7 define static variable for static class in Netbeans 8

Tags: php, class, netbeans, static, php-7

I using Netbeans 8 latest build for editing PHP 7 code (because the Netbeans 8.1 still not supporting PHP 7), but Netbeans IDE said I do something wrong. What is the proper method for this:

```
<?php

class helloc {
    public static $first = 1;
}

class mainc {
    public static $another = NULL;

    public function example() {
        self::$another = new helloc();
        self::$another::$first = 2;
        echo self::$another::$first;
    }
}

$n = new mainc();
$n->example();

?>
```

NetBeans IDE Dev (Build 201605100002) with PHP7 said ERROR for this line:

> self::$another::$first = 2;
>
> unexpected ::

Also, this line had error too:

> echo self::$another::$first;
>   unexpected ::

What is the proper usage for this?
If I start this code, it's working without error. It's OK? Or Netbeans IDE bug?

How can I declare the $another variable? NULL is ok? Or other ways?
I want to declare $another as static "helloc" class at this example.
I want to access variable from this static class. I know, I can declare a get/set functions and it's really nicer but it's other question what is the better.

I just want to create a proper PHP7 code.

Comment: I don't understand ... You are trying to access a static variable which class is referencde in another static variable. This makes no sense ! You don't need to `$self::$another::$first`, since `$first` is static, `helloc::$first` is enough.
You probably have a conceptual problem that you should solve before going on coding ;).
PHP7 and Netbeans have nothing to do with this.

Comment: But this also working what I included as example. I'm newbie in static objects + PHP :-) So, what is the definition the static class? Class with at least 1 static variable? Or a class, what defined as static variable? Like static $abc = NULL; then self:$abc = new xclass(); ?

Comment: The syntax you use is valid PHP 7 (but not PHP 5) syntax. However it is very unusual (so no surprise Netbeans doesn't recognize it) and very likely not what you want to do. Generally use of static variables is discouraged anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 1, solution maybe for my own question:

```
class helloc {
    public static $first = 1;
    public $last = 3;
}

class mainc {
    public $another = NULL;
    public function example() {
        helloc::$first = 2;
        echo helloc::$first;
        $this->another = new helloc();
        $this->another->last = 4;
        echo $this->another->last;
    }
}

$n = new mainc();
$n->example();
```

So, this is the proper usage with PHP7 if in class had static and non-static variables?

For access static variables, no need to use new ().
For non-static need to create with new (), right?